# Convert 2 arrays into key value object javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

I have an array with headers - say `["language", "name", "code"]` 
and an array of arrays of values - for example 
`[["English", "Matt", "2D"], ["Croatian", "Dana", "8S"], ["Russian", "Ivan", "2W"]]`.

I am trying to obtain an array of objects, like so:

```
[ 
  {language: English, name: Matt, code: 2D}, 
  {language: Croatian, name: Dana, code: 8S}, 
  {language: Russian, name: Ivan, code: 2W} 
]
```

Any elegant way to do this without nested for loops?

Comment: `arr.map(values => Object.fromEntries(_.zip(headers, values)))`

Comment: What's wrong with nested loops? It won't be more efficient than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let props=["language", "name", "code"];
let data=[["English", "Matt", "2D"], ["Croatian", "Dana", "8S"], ["Russian", "Ivan", "2W"]];
let result=data.map( (innerArray) =>{let obj={};innerArray.forEach( (innerData,index) =>{obj[props[index]]=innerData;});return obj;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const props = ["language", "name", "code"];
const values = [["English", "Matt", "2D"], ["Croatian", "Dana", "8S"], ["Russian", "Ivan", "2W"]];
const formatted = values.map(value => ({
  [props[0]]: value[0],
  [props[1]]: value[1],
  [props[2]]: value[2],
}));
```

Or like this:

```
const formatted4 = values.map(value => {
  let v = {};
  props.forEach((prop, i) => {
    v = {
      ...v,
      [prop]: value[i]
    }
  });
  return v;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignmentt) (assuming you're sure your data format stays the same) :

```
const newArr = [];
for(const [language, name, code] of yourDataArray){
  //do whatever you want with the variables language, name, code
  newArr.push({
    language: language,
    name: name,
    code: code
  })
}
```

Comment: how is Object.fromEntries() come into play in the above code?

Comment: @Cipriana you're right, it does not. I just remembered that `Object.fromEntries()` accepts an array of iterables. I forgot that they should be key-value pairs which does not apply to your case

Answer (score 0):

**You can create this without complexity, if the data count is constant, using ES6***

```
var dataList = [["English", "Matt", "2D"], ["Croatian", "Dana", "8S"], ["Russian", "Ivan", "2W"]];
    let myList = [];
    for([language, name, code] of dataList)
      myList.push({language, name, code});
    console.log(myList);
```